# How to uninstall shower knobs

Tags: plumbing, shower, knobs

I am trying to change these shower knobs/valve/stem as they are leaking from there base and there is so much salt stains.

I live in a condo where there is no access panel. To get water supply turned off, to try anything, off whole building supply needs to be off. This gives me anxiety as I can't request for longer shut off time for trial and errors. I can't seem to find any brand name. Please guide me in any way possible. Thank you!

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHU1T.jpg)

Comment: It looks like some corrosion and mineral buildup around the faucet handles and the diverter. Most of that can be cleaned off with vinegar or a decalcifying cleaner. Unless you're looking to upgrade the fixtures I'm not sure you need to replace them. If the tub faucet is leaking you may only need a cartridge or washer replacement. You'll still need to get the water turned of but first tell us what the specific problem is other than the minerals forming at the faucet handles.

Comment: Hi, apart from the mineral deposit, there is little water stream which leaks from the knob trim when knobs are turned on. I was thinking to change the shower system if it is easy fo a new DIYer, if not then I will wait for them to fail and get professional help.

Comment: This **is indeed** a failure and needs to be addressed immediately because a leak from the stem area (likely a packing leak) could be allowing water to trickle into the wall. It is not a simple job for a novice and I recommend you hire it done because of your time constraint. If you had plenty of time to learn, we would walk you through comprehensive repair...

Comment: It is not possible to repair the valves without turning off the water supply to them.

Comment: So, I was looking into it more, I found "Royal cleved" written on it. I learned how to unscrew the octagonal cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the control handle then unscrew the octagonal cover this should reveal the valve top.

take photos and measurements. go to the hardware store and buy as washer kit to rebuild the valve

Now turn ff the water supply (or supplies)

turn the valves on and make sure that the is not a fast stream of water.
now remove the top part of the valves (it unscrews)

screw the control stem into top part of the valve stem in until it come out through the back and replace the O rings.

this is a good time to also replace the washer that controls the water.

lubricate and reassemble using a new fibre washer where the valve body closes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed steps.